# Where is the positive and negative holes on the arduino mini breadboard?

Tags: arduino-uno, breadboard

I have the mini arduino breadboard. The pins go from A to J and 1 to 17. On the larger breadboard, there are symbols + and -. My breadboard doesn't have those two sections to put wires in. Does anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 6):

> Does anyone know what to do?

Do whatever you want to do.

There's nothing special about the +/- rails of a breadboard - they're just chunks of metal that go along instead of across, and are longer, with more holes, and someone has helpfully coloured them red/blue and added some symbols.

If you want a common place for + and - then just choose a common place for + and -.